Static html webapp with Azure SSO in Go
I'm using MKDocs to generate Docs to my projects. MKDocs generates all HTML files.
What I need is to serve this HTML files in a Go Lang webApp with SSO.
I'm new to Go Lang (started today) and I'm stucked at SSO Authentication.
I can serve my static webapp using the following code:
package main
import (
     "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".public"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

However, how can I apply Azure SSO to Authenticate all mkdocs HTML pages? Is there a way to do that without pointing to each route?
I tried using gofiber and some ChatGPT answers, but all I got was a lot of error messages.
